# Starting docker kills ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, docker

I have an interesting issue on SLES12SP2 where I type service docker start and then I lose connection to ssh from putty... however I can ssh from Linux to Linux with no problems.... Why would docker kill / prevent me from ssh?

The IP routes look good and my interface is still there... If I reboot the server ssh comes back but as soon as I start docker it kills it from putty and I have to use linux to linux.

Comment: Docker probably sets up a network starting with 172.17.0.0 and you're already using the same network to access it, or something similar.

Comment: Hi, no I am using 10.100.0.X as my eth0 IP address

Comment: ok, bad guess then, can't find better from the informations available